# Java 8/9/10 - Concise programming

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a way to represent the following code in a more concise manner in Java 8/9/10

```
     public boolean check(){
        Optional<X> x = someMethod();
        if (x.isPresent()) {
            return someOtherMethod(x.get());
        } else {
            logger.error("x is empty!");
            return false;
        }
     }
```

Comment: `someMethod().map(x->someOtherMethod(x.get())).orElse(false);`

Comment: @HadiJ How do I log?